# Can a constructor for a class be built with multiple parameters?

Tags: c++

I am wanting to have a constructor so that I can build my object as such: `Student student(age, first, last, email)`, and the object will be be built using my setter functions. This is so that I can have a nice one line that set's all of the variables I need for that object.

Below should make what I am trying to do more clear:

This is what I would envision the constructor to look like so that inside another function I can build an object and have the values already set.

```cpp
Student s(age, first, last);
```

--

```cpp
Student::Student(int age, string first, string last) {
   setAge(age);
   setFirst(first);
   setLast(last);
}
```

I have been away from hard languages like cpp for a long time, so I hope this isn't too rudimentary for you all.

Comment: Are you asking if constructors can be defined to have multiple parameters? It seems like that's what you did in the code you provided.

Comment: ***Can a constructor for a class be built with multiple parameters?*** Yes. Didn't you already do that?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but a constructor can have multiple parameters and a class can have multiple constructors. Hope that helps

Comment: This is a *good* way to do things! If you don't set all the values in the class in the constructor then you have a partially-constructed object at the end and bad things can happen like getting member variables that are uninitialized.

Comment: Are you having problems doing that?

Comment: You might look here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list for the standard way to make constructors. Normally, setter functions are not used but they can be with some care.

Comment: Did you try it? Did you encounter any errors? Can you post them if you did?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux To be honest, it doesn't add much to the discussion other than a different way to accomplish the Asker's goal. if Id been paying attention I wouldn't even have brought it up. Doug already had a few comments earlier, so I'm removing the comment and upvoting his. As for terminology, like *that* matters in programming.

Comment: @user4581301 It might not matter for programming, but it does for discussing it. And that's pretty much what this site does. For what it's worth the standard says *"no initialization is performed"* in that case, but I can't find a formal definition for "uninitialized", though my understanding is that it means that it underwent no initialization.

Comment: I should know better than to use sarcasm on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in many of the comments, C++ does allow this and you should use a member initializer list.

```
class Student
{
    public:

    Student(int age, std::string const& firstName, std::string const& lastName)
    : m_age(age)
    , m_firstName(firstName)
    , m_lastName(lastName) 
    {

    }

    private:

    int m_age;
    std::string m_firstName;
    std::string m_lastName;
};
```

Then you can construct a student like so:

```
Student s(21, "Jane", "Doe");
```